# Forest - Recombining tree

Tags: tikz-pgf, forest

I am new to tikz and want to draw a recombining / merging binomail tree with the package forest. I originally used the solution found in [Tikz-tree merging/recombining nodes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/588153/tikz-tree-merging-recombining-nodes), but since I also use non-merging trees with forrest, I would prefer a single solution.
Thus, is it possible to merge both nodes labeled 5 below?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{automata}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows.meta,positioning}

\newcommand{\iddots}{\reflectbox{$\ddots$}}

\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
    \begin{forest}
for tree={
     semithick,
    minimum size=1.3em, inner sep=0pt,
    math content,
% tree
    l sep =12mm,
    s sep = 6mm,
/tikz/arr/.style = { -{Triangle[angle=45:2pt 3]}, shorten >=1pt},
/tikz/ELS/.style = {% Edge Label Style
              pos=0.5, node
              font=\footnotesize, text=blue, anchor=#1},
EL/.style={if n=1{edge label={node[ELS=east]{$#1$}}}
                 {edge label={node[ELS=west]{$#1$}}}}
%%%% diagram body
[1, label=$\tilde{S}^1$, tier=0
    [2, EL=1-p
        [4, EL=1-p]
        [5, EL=p]
    ]
    [3, EL=p
        [5, EL=1-p]
        [6, EL=p]
    ]
]
\end{forest}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

[image]

With use of `fixed edge angles` option, trick with negative `s sep` equal to nodes width.

**Edit:**
with improved edges labels style:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
%\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
    \begin{forest}
for tree={
% nodes
    circle, draw, semithick,
    minimum size=1.2em, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, %<--- 
    math content,
% tree with fixed angles of edges
   l sep = 11mm,              % <---
  calign = fixed edge angles, % <---
  calign angle = 30,          % <---
   s sep=-1.2em,              % <---
for current and siblings = {anchor=center},
/tikz/arr/.style = {draw=cyan!60, -{Triangle[angle=45:2pt 3]}, 
                    shorten <=\pgflinewidth, shorten >=1pt},
    edge = arr,
%% edge labels
/tikz/ELS/.style = {% Edge Label Style
    pos=0.5, node font=\scriptsize, inner sep=0pt,
    text height=2ex, text depth=0.5ex, text=cyan, anchor=south #1},
EL/.style={if n=1{edge label={node[ELS=east]{$#1$}}}
                 {edge label={node[ELS=west]{$#1$}}}}
        }% end of "for tree"
%%%% diagram body
[1, label=$\tilde{S}^1$
    [2, EL=1-p
        [4, EL=q]
        [5,EL=1-q]
    ]
    [3, EL=p
        [, EL=q]
        [6, EL=1-q]
    ]
]
    \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

**Addendum:**
or the following form:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
%\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
    \begin{forest}
for tree={
% nodes
    circle, draw, semithick,
    minimum size=1.2em, inner sep=0pt,
    anchor=north,   % <--- new
    math content,
% tree
    l sep =12mm,
    s sep = 3mm,
/tikz/arr/.style = {draw=cyan!60, shorten >=1pt, 
                    -{Triangle[angle=45:2pt 3]}},
     edge = arr,
%% edge labels
/tikz/ELS/.style = {% Edge Label Style
    pos=0.5, node font=\tiny, inner sep=0pt,    % <--- changed
    text height=2ex, text depth=0.5ex, text=cyan, anchor=south #1},
EL/.style={if n=1{edge label={node[ELS=east]{$#1$}}}
                 {edge label={node[ELS=west]{$#1$}}}}
        }% end of "for tree"
%%%% diagram body
[1, label=$\tilde{S}^1$
    [2, EL=1-p, calign = last, name=n2  % <--- added calign 
        [4, EL=q]
        [,phantom]          % <--- changed
    ]
    [,phantom[5, name=n5]]  % <--- new
    [3, EL=p, calign = first, name=n3  % <--- added calign 
        [,phantom]          % <--- changed
         [6, EL=1-q]
    ]
]
\draw[arr] (n2) -- (n5) node[ELS=west] {$1-q$};
\draw[arr] (n3) -- (n5) node[ELS=east] {$q$};
    \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Comment: yeah, exactly like this. Since you use fixed angles, does that mean that we can not scale the tree (e.g. make a new generationi?). Why use s sep=-1.2em?

Comment: @Tamar, about scaling: try it.  Let me know if it doesn't work. Trick with `s sep` is used that bot nodes containing 5 (actually one is empty) perfectly overlap.